# Cmd.exe starting a file from batch script containing %20 in the name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created a .bat script allowing me to start all programs I need to stream on twitch. However I am facing a problem with an application. I would like to start the following program: ground%20control.exe

When I type in cmd.exe:

```
start "" "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\ground_control\Ground%20Control.exe"
```

It works.

When I use the exact same command in my .bat file I end up with the following error:

> Impossible to find C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\ground_control\Ground**0**Control.exe

I assume that it is probably a formatting problem. Any help would be much welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In batch files the percent symbol is used to indicate parameter, in your case it is treating %2 as a parameter and due to it being empty, replacing it with empty.

From  this page [Batch Files - Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

> In batch files, the percent sign may be "escaped" by using a double percent sign ( %% ).
>   That way, a single percent sign will be used as literal within the command line, instead of being further interpreted.

So change it to the following in your batch file

```
start "" "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\ground_control\Ground%%20Control.exe"
```